# Android : Grey View instead of back and home button of the screen when using exo player in full screen mode

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer2.x

I have a problem when click on full screen button in exo player like this

and i use this code to make the full screen mode

[image]

```
activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
                if ((activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar != null) {
                    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.hide()
                }
                activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
                val params =
                    first_channel_vp.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                first_channel_vp.layoutParams = params
                fullscreen = true
                first_channel_vp.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved the problem by removing

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from the `MainActivity` root view and it worked perfectly